# Show that $a·(b×c) = det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

Hi. I don't know how to approach to this question. I tried to find the characteristic polynomial but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: It turns out one of the usual formulas for computing the right hand side is exactly the formula for computing the left hand side.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of **what**, exactly?

Comment: Dear Ant: a quick look through your collection of questions, eight in all,  reveals a stubborn pattern of providing only problem statement question (usually in the form of an image, which requires a user with sufficient rep to post the actual image of your problem into your question (when you could have, and should have, typed and formatted the question directly into the question field) , followed by a plea of the form " I don't know how to approach to this question ...".  It doesn't take long for users at mse catch such patterns associated with a specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way of proving this would be by operating in both sides:
3c
$$det(A) = a_1b_2c_3 + a_2b_3c_1 + a_3b_1c_2 - (a_3b_2c_1 + a_2b_1c_3 + a_1b_3c_2).$$

Then, $(b \times c) =(b_2c_3 - b_3c_2,b_3c_1-b_1c_3,b_1c_2-b_2c_1). $

And finally applying the escalar product:

$$ a·(b\times c) = a_1b_2c_3 - a_1b_3c_2 + a_2b_3c_1 - a_2b_1c_3 + a_3b_1c_2 - a_3b_2c_1. $$

Which gives us the same expression!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with known dimensions, you could use algebraic formulas for each. Set $\mathbf{a} = \langle a_x, a_y, a_z\rangle$, using similar assignments for the other vectors, and use algebraic laws of the cross/dot products to compute an algebraic expression and show that this is equal to the determinant (again, by expressing it algebraically. Not the most fun way to prove something, but I think this would be a sound approach.